# Laravel Query Builder use multiple times

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Is it possible to save a query bulider and use it multiple times?

for example, I have a model 'Tour'.

I create a long query buider and paginate it:

```
$tour = Tour::where(...)->orWhere(...)->orderBy(...)->paginate(10);
```

*For example, 97 models qualify for the above query.
"Paginate" method outputs first 10 models qualifying for the query, but I also need to so some operations on all 97 models. 
I don't want to 'repeat myself' writing this long query 2 times.*

**So I want something like:**

> ```
> $query = Tour::where(...)->orWhere(...)->orderBy(...);
>
> $tour1 = $query->paginate(10); 
> $tour2 = $query->get();
> ```

Is that a correct way to do in Laravel? (my version is 5.4).

Comment: Yes.
It is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but it doesn't make any sense because every time a new query will be executed. So this code will work:

```
$query = Tour::where(...)->orWhere(...)->orderBy(...);
$tour1 = $query->paginate(10); 
$tour2 = $query->get();
```

But if you want to execute just one query, you'll need to use collection methods for ordering, filtering and mapping the data. You'll also need to [create Paginator instance manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator):

```
$collection = Tour::where(...)->orWhere(...)->orderBy(...)->get();
$tour1 = // Make Paginator manually.
$tour2 = $collection;
$sortedByName = $collection->sortBy('name');
$activeTours = $collection->where('active', 1);
```

Comment: I'll add how I've created paginator manually:

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
//Get current page: $current_page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage();
// Get items for current page (use values() method to reset the keys): $items = $collection->slice(($current_page - 1) * $paginate, $paginate)->values(); // Get Total of Items $total = $collection->count(); // PAGINATE!:)
$tours = new Paginator($items, $total, $paginate, $current_page, ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]);

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php):

```
$query = Tour::where(...)->orWhere(...)->orderBy(...);
$query1 = clone $query;
$query2 = clone $query;

$tour1 = $query1->paginate(10); 
$tour2 = $query2->get();
```